# How to upload files from location system to GCP Storage using Python in cloud sherr

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have files on my local system ,I'm able to upload to GCP Storage using python by connecting to GCP account using json file. I'm running this python program manually in a command prompt but want use the same program which can read data from my local system or share drive ..any suggestion how we can connect to local system path or share drive path from VM / Cloud shell to upload files to GCP Storage.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: With airflow, use pythonOperator.If you need more guidance, update your question (look at @JohnHanley's link)